# nested dictionary into nested list (of checkboxes)

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, recursion

I have a nested dictionary with the structure `{ "1" : [{"a" : ["p", "q"]}, "b", "c", {"d" : ["h", "w"]}] }`. Here is the [link to the exact data](https://github.com/santoshlinkha/prob_and_stat/blob/main/breakdown.js). The depth can go up to any length, but the dept is finite. I am trying to create a nested list (of checkboxes) with the following code.

```
    import React from "react";

    
    class TagTree extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <React.Fragment>
                    <ul>
                        { 
                            this.props.tag.map( (t) =>                             
                                <li>
                                    { (typeof(t) === "object")? Object.keys(t) : t }
                                </li>
                            )
                        }
                    </ul>
                </React.Fragment>            
            )
        }
    }


    class TagApp extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <TagTree tag={this.props.tagList} />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default TagApp;
```

Here, the input dictionary is passed as  `this.props.tagList`. I have two problems.

1. If I recursively create `TagTree`  at the following line

```
  <li>
      { (typeof(t) === "object")? <TagTree tag={t} /> : t }
  </li>
```

I get an error

2. I need to display the key before displaying it's contents.

My thanks for your help. The error is as follows.

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
localhost/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
localhost/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
localhost/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `TagTree`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at li
    at TagTree (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1301:1)
    at div
    at TagApp (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1330:1)
    at div
    at div
    at McqApp (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:952:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32:1)
printWarning @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87
error @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:61
validateExplicitKey @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:1078
validateChildKeys @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:1105
jsxWithValidation @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:1276
render @ tag.jsx:7
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19752
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19698
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21611
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
6tag.jsx:8 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.tag.map is not a function
    at TagTree.render (tag.jsx:8:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
render @ tag.jsx:8
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19752
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19698
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21611
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
6tag.jsx:8 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.tag.map is not a function
    at TagTree.render (tag.jsx:8:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
render @ tag.jsx:8
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19752
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:19698
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21611
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
6react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <TagTree> component:

    at TagTree (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1301:1)
    at li
    at ul
    at TagTree (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1301:1)
    at div
    at TagApp (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1330:1)
    at div
    at div
    at McqApp (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:952:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32:1)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
tag.jsx:8 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.tag.map is not a function
    at TagTree.render (tag.jsx:8:1)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19752:1)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:19698:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21611:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
```

Comment: What data is inside of `this.props.tag`? You need to first show the contents/structure of this so we can think about what a good unique identifier for the key would be. BTW this error is more of a warning, react prints all warnings as errors.

Comment: @adsy `tag={this.props.tagList}` and `this.props.tagList` contains the input dictionary structure.

Comment: Can I see that input dictionary structure (I know this sounds orthogonal, but it is a necessary step to figure out how to create a `key` that is unique)

Comment: This amount of nesting suggests that perhaps you are making this more complicated than they need to be. Try to make it simpler. Or maybe the abstract description of your nested structure just makes it difficult to understand it. Are the keys and values really just single digits and characters? Or do they more meaningful words?

Comment: Also the fact that you have a list which contains both dictionaries and strings suggests that you are not using the correct data structure.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `csv_file => pandas grouping function => json_output`. The structure is an array that contains either dictionary or string. If it is dictionary, then it's values are arrays and same pattern repeats.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Here is the [link to the real data](https://github.com/santoshlinkha/prob_and_stat/blob/main/breakdown.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my previous answer. Here is a fully working solution that uses recursion, and has accurate keys.

The trick is that you need to handle array cases, object cases, and plain strings differently.

You also need to pass around a path which is a string that will be used for the key -- recursively adding to it on each loop so that the context of the next loop has a unique base key to build from.

Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-julien-jdo9in?file=/src/App.js:0-28025
The other answer to change data structure is also legit as well, but thought I'd drop this here if you wanted to keep it/couldnt change it.

[image: output]

```
import React from "react";

class TagTree extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul>
          {Array.isArray(this.props.tag) ? (
            this.props.tag.map((t, index) => {
              return (
                <TagTree
                  tag={t}
                  key={this.props.path + index}
                  path={this.props.path + index}
                />
              );
            })
          ) : typeof this.props.tag === "object" ? (
            Object.entries(this.props.tag).map(([key, t], index) => (
              <>
                <TagTree
                  key={this.props.path + key}
                  tag={key}
                  path={this.props.path + key}
                />
                <TagTree
                  key={this.props.path + key + index}
                  tag={t}
                  path={this.props.path + key + index}
                />
              </>
            ))
          ) : (
            <li>{this.props.tag}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class TagApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TagTree tag={this.props.tagList} path="" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TagApp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a list of objects with fixed keys. For example, each objects could look something like this

```
courses = [
    {
        "name": "Algebra",
        "topics": [
            {
                "name": "Matrices",
                "topics": [
                    // ...
                ]
            },
            // ...
        ]
    },
    // ...
]
```

Now recursively descending into this is much easier because every object will always have a `"name"` and `"topics"`.

Comment: I fixed it, I was passing the dictionary instead of I was passing the values. `<TagTree tag={t[Object.keys(t)]} />`  instead of  `<TagTree tag={t} />`. Thank you for your support. Maybe you could include that in your answer.

Comment: Also, your idea eliminates my discrepancy.